# Makefile - compiling library and executable when no changes made

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

So, I can understand what the problem is here, but I can't quite figure out how to fix it -- Because it is compiling files from a different directory, but throwing the .a library file and executable into the root...It seems that the makefile is expecting them to be in their source directory, and that's why it rebuilds every time even when no changes are made.

Problem is, my school is very strict on folder structure, so it needs to compile exactly how it is, I just need to figure out how to let the makefile know the executable and library file DO exist, in the root directory.

Here is my Makefile:

```
NAME = fillit
LIB = libft.a

CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -Werror
RM = /bin/rm -rf

SRC = main.c validation.c create_piece.c game_board.c solver.c tables.c \
    trimmer.c

LIBSRC = ft_putchar.c ft_putstr.c ft_strcpy.c ft_strnew.c ft_strdel.c \
    ft_strequ.c ft_putendl.c ft_error.c

LIBLIST  :=  $(shell ls -1 libft | grep .c$$)
LIBOBJ   :=  $(LIBLIST:.c=.o)
LIBOBJ   :=  $(addprefix libft/, $(LIBOBJ))

SRCLIST  :=  $(shell ls -1 src | grep .c$$)
SRCOBJ   :=  $(SRCLIST:.c=.o)
SRCOBJ   :=  $(addprefix src/, $(SRCOBJ))

.PHONY: all $(NAME) lib

all: $(NAME)

libft/%.o: libft/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

src/%.o: src/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

lib:
    ar rc $(LIB) $(LIBOBJ)
    ranlib $(LIB)

debug:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(addprefix libft/, $(LIBLIST)) $(addprefix src/, $(SRCLIST)) -g -o fillit

$(NAME): $(LIBOBJ) $(SRCOBJ) lib
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SRCOBJ) -L. -lft -o fillit

clean:
    $(RM) $(SRCOBJ)
    $(RM) $(LIBOBJ)


fclean: clean
    $(RM) $(NAME)
    $(RM) $(LIB)

re: fclean all

re-db: fclean debug
```

It's working fine for compiling the .o files, it only does that once, but if I continue to type make, it still compiles this part:

```
➜  fillit git:(master) ✗ make
ar rc libft.a libft/ft_memset.o libft/ft_putchar.o libft/ft_putendl.o libft/ft_putstr.o libft/ft_strcpy.o libft/ft_strdel.o libft/ft_strequ.o libft/ft_strnew.o
ranlib libft.a
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror src/create_piece.o src/game_board.o src/main.o src/solver.o src/tables.o src/trimmer.o src/validation.o -L. -lft -o fillit
```

Comment: Your `lib` target has no dependencies so it is always run.

Comment: and what about the executable being made still?

Comment: Well, it depends on lib which always needs to be rebuilt causing the exec target to always be rebuilt.

Comment: I tried adding $(LIB) as a dependency, but that didn't work. I guess I'm still a bit confused on exactly how dependencies work. I've been reading up on it, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I've fixed the library compiling by changing lib to $(LIB) -- it's still compiling the executable though.

Answer (score 1):

Want to thank kaylum for pointing me in the right direction, I have figured out how to solve this problem. I changed `lib` to `$(LIB)` and removed $(NAME) and lib from the phony list. Working makefile:

```
NAME = fillit
LIB = libft.a

CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -Werror
RM = /bin/rm -rf

SRC = main.c validation.c create_piece.c game_board.c solver.c tables.c \
    trimmer.c

LIBSRC = ft_putchar.c ft_putstr.c ft_strcpy.c ft_strnew.c ft_strdel.c \
    ft_strequ.c ft_putendl.c ft_error.c

LIBLIST  :=  $(shell ls -1 libft | grep .c$$)
LIBOBJ   :=  $(LIBLIST:.c=.o)
LIBOBJ   :=  $(addprefix libft/, $(LIBOBJ))

SRCLIST  :=  $(shell ls -1 src | grep .c$$)
SRCOBJ   :=  $(SRCLIST:.c=.o)
SRCOBJ   :=  $(addprefix src/, $(SRCOBJ))

.PHONY: all

all: $(NAME)

libft/%.o: libft/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

src/%.o: src/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

$(LIB):
    ar rc $(LIB) $(LIBOBJ)
    ranlib $(LIB)

debug:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(addprefix libft/, $(LIBLIST)) $(addprefix src/, $(SRCLIST)) -g -o fillit

$(NAME): $(LIBOBJ) $(SRCOBJ) $(LIB)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SRCOBJ) -L. -lft -o $(NAME)

clean:
    $(RM) $(SRCOBJ)
    $(RM) $(LIBOBJ)


fclean: clean
    $(RM) $(NAME)
    $(RM) $(LIB)

re: fclean all

re-db: fclean debug
```